# SHELL add double quotes at the beginning and end of specific variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, double-quotes

I have variable in shell script which takes a value in variable $var1.
If I do `echo $var1` I will get for example value Boston.
My desired value is `"Boston"`

I tried couple of cases:

```
var1=""$var1""
var1="""$var1"""
```

But in both cases I am getting as result `'$var1'` but I want `"Boston"`
Please for solution do not mention solution which contains Boston in it. I would appreciate if you can use only `var1` in the whole script so it can be more clear! "Boston" just needs to be output of the script execution and for initiliztion for the variable var1.

Thanks

Comment: Try 

var1="\"Boston\""

Comment: Please do not mention specific value!!!

Comment: I want to make it more general and not with specific value. use var1 instead

Comment: Can you be more specific..? this works for variables as well, just escape the qutes you want in the echo out.. a="\"$var1\""

Comment: @Riyas I cannot change how I define var1. It is always at the start var1=Boston

Comment: I f I do var2="\"$var1\"  then I am getting new line and > sign

Comment: There's a double quote missing there :) .. use like var2="\"$var1\""

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Escaping quote sign with backslash is what you need

```
var1=Boston
var1=\"${var1}\"
echo $var1
"Boston"
```

Additionally, curly braces is safe notation for variables

Comment: works great. Thank you!!! And one more question please: if I want to have maybe as result this: 'Boston' what do I need to change? Thanks. I will accept answer in few minutes

Comment: you need to change just one sign  
single quote is escaped the same way as the double one: 

\"  -> \'

Comment: Downvote: *Not* quoting the argument to `echo` makes you do all kinds of weird complications which could be solved very easily.

Comment: `function stpu() {
  git stash push -u -m \""${@}"\"
}` is not working for me.